# How can i prevent external documentation files from being copied to bin folder in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, publish, vs-web-application-project

I'm (still) using Visual Studio 2008. I have an ASP.NET web application with some files in a folder at the root level of my project called "resources". That folder includes jQuery includes, etc., as well as a PDF file that is documentation for the users of the application. The directory structure looks like this:

```
Project
  |__ Properties
  |__ References
  |__ (etc.)
  |__ bin
  |__ (etc.)
  |__ resources
        |__ (etc.)
        |__ docs
              |__ DocumentationFile.pdf
```

The issue I'm having is that `resources/docs/` (empty folder) is being created in `/bin` when I publish the application. The folder and its contents are being copied to the proper location at the root level as well, so everything works.

But my OCD tendencies force me to try and figure out why I'm getting the extra copy in `/bin`. Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

I have the file `DocumentationFile.pdf` marked as "Content" under "Properties" in the Solution Explorer, before I did that it wasn't being copied over at all. And I used to have the "Copy to Output Directory" property set to "Copy if newer", but found that didn't seem to be necessary, so I changed it back to "Do not copy" (though I don't know what would happen if I update the document, would the new version get published?)

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out - the `bin/resources/docs` folder was a leftover empty folder that was cluttering up my project directory, left over from when I had the "Copy to Output Directory" property on my documentation file set to "Copy if newer".

Comment: However, I still don't quite understand the "Copy to Output Directory" property - if it is set to "Do not copy" (as it is now), will my documentation file get updated when I publish it if I update it in the "source"?